# Convert xx:xx into xxhxx in JS

Tags: javascript, date, time, converters

I have time data coming to me in Json format: "7:00", "7:30", "8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", … ]... until "18:00"
basically over a day I have 30-minute slots in this format.

I display them in a web page and I want to display them in the format 7h30 / 8h / 8h30/ 9h etc.

Basically, I'm trying to remove the ':', replace them with h and remove the 00 when there are any.

I guess best practice would be to convert my data so that JS recognizes it as time and knows it's hours?

I've tried this

```
slots.replace(':', 'h').replace('00', ' ');
```

it's ok but the aim is to recognize the data as time. So I guess i have to create a function to divide the time in minutes or seconds and pass it into time for js ?
I tell myself that if the site is on a browser in English or another language, it would be great if the hours were converted accordingly. For the moment, replace works with typical hours 7:00 - 8:00 ... 14h  15h which is ok in french, italian, etc. but if I pass in 7am / 4pm it will not be great...

What do you think?

Comment: Its kinda easy to do. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Those are presumably strings, so I'd suggest [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), or [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

Comment: I would not fixate too much on the half hour case and just make two cases. One with "no minutes" and one "with minutes". You never know when the requirements are going to change and/or you suddenly get "07:15" afterall. You dont want to end up with 60 replaces.

Comment: Your code fails because [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not change the original string yet returns a new one. You have to reassign it. `x = x.replace()`.

Comment: Plus `slots` seems plural, as if an array, so `replace` won't work on it. You will need to iterate the array to make the changes.

Comment: I've edited my post to explain better my will. Thanks to everybody that helps me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you're obtaining your "*time data*" in JSON format, so I'm assuming that you've converted that JSON into an Array of times. In the code below I create the Array, but obviously that can be skipped if you already have your array of times.

That said, this is one approach, explanatory comments are in the code:

```js
// defining a named function to generate the times, with given increments;
// the function is written with Arrow syntax, and passes in an Opts argument
// which defaults to an empty Object-literal if no argument(s) are passed by
// the user:
const timeSteps = (opts = {}) => {
    // default settings:
    let settings = {
      // start: Integer, the hour of the day (24hr format) that
      //        the time-steps should start:
      start: 7,
      // end:   Integer, the hour of the day (24hr format) that
      //        the time-steps should finish:
      end: 18,
      // increments: Integer, the number of minutes between increments (there
      //             are no sanity checks, so ideally 60 should be divisible
      //             by this number:
      increments: 30
    };

    // updating the settings Object, using Object.keys() to retrieve an Array
    // of the keys of the opts Object, iterating over that Array with
    // Array.prototype.forEach():
    Object.keys(opts).forEach(
      // passing the current key, of the array of keys, into the function,
      // in which we update the settings[key] property to be equal to the
      // value of the opts[key] property-value:
      (key) => settings[key] = opts[key]
    );

    // using destructuring assignment to instantiate the named variables
    // to be the property-value of those properties from the settings
    // Object:
    let {
      start,
      end,
      increments
    } = settings,
    // defining the duration (in hours):
    duration = end - start,
      // number of minutes in one hour:
      hours = 60,
      // creating an Array, using Array.from() and an Object literal
      // with its length defined as hours / increments (to get the
      // number of steps per hour):
      hourSteps = Array.from({
        length: hours / increments
        // iterating over the created Array, using Array.prototype.map()
        // to return a new Array based on the old:
      }).map(
        // here we don't use the (undefined) array-value, but we do
        // use the index (i) of the current array-value from the
        // created Array; we return the value of the current index
        // multiplied by the number of hours multiplied by the
        // fraction created by 1 divided by the number of increments
        // per hour (so for thirty minute increments:
        // i * (60 * (1/(60/30))
        // i * (60 * (1/2)
        // i * (60 * 0.5)
        // i * 30 (this works, but I think it's horribly written and
        // should be simplified):
        (_, i) => i * (hours * (1 / (hours / increments)))
      );
    // here we create another Array using the same approach, this time based
    // on the duration (calculated earlier):
    return Array.from({
      length: duration
      // iterating over that Array with Array.prototype.map():
    }).map(
      // passing in the index of the array-element:
      (_, i) => {
        // returning the result of the following call to Array.prototype.map()
        // on the hourSteps Array:
        return hourSteps.map(
          // here we use a template literal to:
          // increase the value of start by the value of the index to increase the
          // time over the course of the array processing, calling toString() on
          // the resulting number, and then padding the start of that string to
          // 2 places, padded with the 0 character.
          // we then have a literal ':' character,
          // then we convert the hStep to a String, with Number.prototype.toString()
          // chaining it with String.prototype.padEnd(), to convert a single-digit
          // number to a String of length = 2, padded with 0 characters:
          (hStep) => `${(start + i).toString().padStart(2,'0')}:${hStep.toString().padEnd(2,0)}`
        )
        // flattening the 2 dimensional Array to a single dimension:
      }).flat();
  },
  // getting the times:
  incrementedHours = timeSteps(),
  // creating an <li> element:
  li = document.createElement('li'),
  // creating a document fragment, to minimise the number paints
  // the browser has to execute:
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  // getting a reference to the element to which the times will be added:
  list = document.querySelector('ol');

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the incrementedHours Array:
incrementedHours.forEach(
  // passing in the time from the Array of times:
  (time) => {
    // cloning the created <li> element:
    let clone = li.cloneNode();
    // setting the text-content of the clone to
    // be equal to the time; then using String.prototype.replace()
    // to replace either ":" or "00", globally (so replacing both),
    // using an anonymous Arrow function, with a conditional (ternary)
    // operator to see if the matched sequence is equal to ':', if it
    // is we replace that ':' character with 'h' or, otherwise, with
    // an empty-string:
    clone.textContent = time.replace(/\:|00/g, (match) => match === ':' ? 'h' : '');
    // appending the clone to the document-fragment:
    fragment.append(clone);
  });

// appending the fragment to the <ol>
list.append(fragment);
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 400 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
ol,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.4em;
  width: clamp(10em, 70vw, 700px);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<ol></ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h8a0tr5w/).

References:

- [`Array.protoype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
- [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`String.prototype.padEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd).
- [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

```
slots = slots.replace(':', 'h').replace('00', '')
```

Comment: Given the original data is an array, I'd do `times.map(time => time.replace(':','h').replace('00',''))`. :-)